# How to override the Django generic base View's dispatch method?

Tags: django

If I write a class that inherits from Django's generic base View, what is the correct way to override its dispatch method?  The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#view) seems to indicate it can be overridden but the example doesn't show exactly how to do it.

If I do this,

```
class MyView(View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponse('Hello, world!')
```

Django says,

```
NameError: name 'dispatch' is not defined.
```

If I then change the dispatch statement to this,

```
response = self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Django says,

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Why do you call `dispatch` in `get`? Normally `dispatch` will call get, so you get in a mutual recursive loop, hence the error.

Comment: Why do you want to override `dispatch` in the first place? Can you explain *what* you aim to do?

Comment: Read [this](https://spapas.github.io/2018/03/19/comprehensive-django-cbv-guide/), It will change your life I assure you that

Comment: And Willem is right, `dispatch` will return get, calling it from get will cause that weird recursion limit exceeded exception

Comment: I didn't have a reason to do this.  It's just that the documentation seemed to imply that it could be done and so I wanted to understand how it would be done.  I was just curious.

Comment: @nde: well it can be done. But `dispatch` is used to determine what method (`get`, `post`, etc.) to call (and call that method), so calling it from `get`, is the other way around, and will get the system stock in infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks @AhmedI.Elsayed.  I'm actually coding each of the CBVs in the API just to understand exactly what they do and under what circumstances I might use each of them.

Comment: @nde: another site that is useful is https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/ here for each view, you can see the code (based on the MRO), so you can understand what code exactly runs per view.

Comment: see this if you'll use DRF http://www.cdrf.co/ , similar to ccbv

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That ccbv is very enlightening.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The documentation seems to indicate it can be overridden but the example doesn't show exactly how to do it.

You can override every method (except for some of the Python builtins, etc., but that is not relevant here).

Overriding `dispatch` is however not that common, since `dispatch` basically inspects the method of the request (GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, etc.), to the corresponding method `get`, `post`, `patch`, `put`, `delete`, etc.

So, as you found out, if you *call* the `dispatch()` method in the `get()` method, you get a mutual recursive situation. Here `dispatch` will call `get`, and `get` will call `dispatch`. So that will keep calling each other, until the call stack is exhausted.

There are some cases when a view overrides the `dispatch` method, for example the [`LogoutView` does this [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L117-L123):

> ```
> class LogoutView(SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin, TemplateView):
>
>     # …
>
>     @method_decorator(never_cache)
>     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         auth_logout(request)
>         next_page = self.get_next_page()
>         if next_page:
>             # Redirect to this page until the session has been cleared.
>             return HttpResponseRedirect(next_page)
>         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
> ```

Here the `dispatch` method will ensure that a `logout` call is made for the given user. But the `get` method will not call the `dispatch` method again.